# Deep FinRL Library - Kernel Died

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, reinforcement-learning, finrl

I am currently installing the FinRl Library but when i import the finrl library using "from finrl.meta.preprocessor.yahoodownloader import YahooDownloader" it says the kernel has died and is restarting. Other libraries are working fine but not sure why this isnt working.
[Please see the picture of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6E3Mu.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: sounds like a problem with jupyter and not with the library itself